# JQueryMobile Loadmore options

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile

Any idea how to implement the load more option in JQueryMobile. In my application I need to pull lots of data and would like to load top 20 and make the user load more data by clicking the "load more" data option on the last row of Listview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#loadmore-link').click(function() {
    // remove the "load more" link
    $(this).remove();

    // get more LI elements (probably with a $.get())
    $('ul').append('<li>More list items</li>');

    // update the list view
    $('ul').listview('refresh');
});
```