# Phone gap jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Can any one tell me how to implement load more button.

I have a list that contains 100 to 150 urls to images. I have to push the to screen 10 once and wait for user to tap the load more button at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('#loadmore-link').click(function() {
    // remove the "load more" link
    $(this).remove();

    // get more LI elements (probably with a $.get())
    $('ul').append('<li>More list items</li>');

    // update the list view
    $('ul').listview('refresh');
});
```

Took from : [JQueryMobile Loadmore options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005670/jquerymobile-loadmore-options)